# Merge conflict disappears automatically after invoking mergetool

Tags: git

In the code repository I am working with, when I do a pull, Git warns of a merge conflict and puts out an error message that says:

```
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

So, then I run 'git mergetool'. It gives a list of merge tool candidates, then a message:

```
Merging fileA
Normal merge conflict for fileA
{local}: modified file
{remote}: modified file
Hit return to start merge resoution tool (kdiff3):
```

When I hit return, it immediately returns back to the command prompt. If I now execute git citool, I see the file has been merged correctly. This seems to happen only in cases where Git could have easily auto-merged the files, i.e. adjacent lines were modified, but the same lines weren't touched in the 2 repos. So my question is why I am getting an 'automatic merge failed' message in the first place?

Is it the case that hitting 'return' activates kdiff3 which then resolves the conflict automatically without my intervention?  If so, is there a way to configure Git such that I don't even get the first 'Automatic merge failed' message?

I thought kdiff3 just brings up the GUI for the user to merge manually and doesn't have any auto-resolution capabilities.

Comment: Can you show us the conflicted region of the files (ancestor / yours / theirs) in question?

Answer (score 2):

```
Is it the case that hitting 'return' activates kdiff3 which then resolves the conflict automatically without my intervention?
```

Yes. kdiff3 tries to solve conflicts automatically. Git is not that much intelligent. Git is not made to resolve conflicts. It relies on third party application for that.

Comment: *So my question is why I am getting an 'automatic merge failed' message in the first place?*